# while importing file in react I am getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';''

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>lets build amazon clone</h1>
      <Header />
    </div>
    // header
    // Home

  );
}

export default App;
```

I am new to react I'm Getting this error while compiling

> Line 2:31:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: You have a `''` after the import

Answer (score 0):

unwanted '' is there after your Header import

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>lets build amazon clone</h1>
      <Header />
    </div>
    // header
    // Home

  );
}

export default App;
```